# What if zombie apocalypse happened in 18th century

Tags: apocalypse, alternate-history, history, zombies, geopolitics

What would happen if a zombie appeared in 18th century Italy?

More specifically, a walking Dead style zombie "spawning" in Turin, The Duchy of Savoy on noon, 3 of May, 1715.Turin is far upriver in the Po. I know the science isn't definite in walking dead zombies but would one of the walkers falling in the river affect all the towns downstream?

Also, would the average farmer be better off? Their Snaphance or Flintlock guns would probably take too long to reload but would a scythe or other farming implement be able to beat away a zombie?

And are mountains effective zombie barriers?

P.S. On Wikipedia it said that Turin's population after the War of the Spanish Succession was 90,000 people. Here's a map I also found on wikipedia.(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7f/Europe_1714.png)

P.P.S. The reason I started it in Turin, Italy is I though this question should be specific but if you happen to know a lot about, say, Polish history, you can what would happen if it started in Warsaw of Krakow or some other place that you know more about.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Ethalba. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is not a discussion forum; we handle specific problems, rather than vague requests for plot ideas. In the future, please refrain from asking questions where you can easily include "the possibilities are virtually endless," as such questions are inherently inappropriate for the site.

Answer (score 3):

Without access to shotguns, the populace would need to resort mainly to bladed weapons or maces.  Pole Axes, lumber axes, etc.  Swords aren't really effective as they tend lack the power and momentum to easily decapitate a moving object.

I'm no expert in Italian history, but I'd bet there were more bridges back then than there are now (pontoon bridges for example).  They wouldn't really limit the zombie advance, it'll just get filtered into deadly corridors.

I don't think that mountains are good for barriers, but they'd slow progress.

Comment: Fords and ferries but not so many bridges normally, a deep wide river with no ferry becomes an impassable barrier

Answer (score 1):

[Back in the 18th century fire weapons already existed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musket) , I don't really know who had access to them, but they were there.

Something to take in account is a zombie apocalypse is kinda difficult to achieve, even in 18th century, where humans right where not established yet, so if a *group of leper people is trying to eat your population* you would probably sent your soldiers in armour which teeth cannot penetrate and slaughter them (I think there were armours still around).

Farmers would be in a good position if they know in advance what was going on, and information in that time didn't travel that fast, you know, but still is not that easy to asume that because a farmer may get angry if a random guy just trespass it's farm and kill because he gets afraid when he see it.

Mountains may be a good option, but remember people in elder times didn't have the tools we currently have to survive in the mountains, and of course, it depends on the mountain.

Comment: I did some research and the common type of Musket during that time was a flintlock musket which takes at 10 to 30 seconds to reload. I also found a Pistol called the Queen Anne Pistol that was popular in Britain at that time but probably not relevant as the zombie apocalypse would probably never even get out of Italy.